# Use a dash for multiple pages in a row in the list of acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the `glossaries` package to create a list of acronyms in my thesis. My question is how to change a style of pages location list in acronyms section, if there are several pages in a row? I would like to display it like

**VIA** very important acronym 2, 7-11, 22

instead of

**VIA** very important acronym 2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 22

I thought the solution is to redefine the `\glslabel` and tried to do it, but without any success. Searching on this issue also provided no results.

Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
 [
    acronyms,           % create list of acronyms 
    shortcuts,          % acronym commands 
    nopostdot           % no full stop at the end
 ]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries    % to sort 

\newacronym{via}{VIA}{very important acronym}

%%

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary
[
  type = acronym,       % list of acronyms
]
\newpage

Some text with a \ac{via}. 
\newpage

Some more text with the \ac{via}. 
\newpage

And even more text with the \ac{via}. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. How do you biuld your list of acronyms? Do you use `xindy`, `makeindex` or a different option?

Comment: From [Table 1.1 in the User guide of `glossaries`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf#table.1.1) it is clearly stated that using Option 1 (`\makenoidxglossaries` + `\printnoidxglossary`) does not support automatically forming ranges in the location list. Using `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossary`works – that will form ranges for 3 or more consecutive pages

Comment: @sodd Thanks a lot for your answer! Sorry for such a trifling issue)

Comment: @OlegDogadov Happy to help, and no need to be sorry - this package isn't among the basic ones :)